# ReactJS webpack babel: _this2 is undefined when clicking button whose function is passed via a parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, es6-class

No doubt I've missed something really obvious here but I'm trying to do the lynda tutorial "Learning React.js", it's a bit different since I'm using ES6 classes and transpiling using Babel via webpack.

The problem is executing a function **being passed as a parameter to the Note class from the Board class.**

I have a "Note" class which can be described as:

```
remove() {
    this.props.onRemove(this.props.id);
}
//Notes class
render() {
    return (
        <div className="note">
            <p>{this.props.children}</p>
            <span>
                <button onClick={() => this.remove() }>X</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Where **onRemove is a function that's being passed as a prop from Board** to Note like this:

```
//Method in Board class. I map through an array and call this function on each element to create notes.
eachNote(note) {
    return (
        <Note key = { note.id } id = { note.id } onRemove = { (id) => this.remove(id) }>
            { note.note }
        </Note>
    )
}
```

The remove() method in the Board class looks like this:

```
//Remove method in the Board class
remove(id) {
    let notes = this.state.notes.filter(note => note.id !== id);
    this.setState({notes});
}
```

When I click a Note's X button it DOES execute the local function in the note class but then DOESN'T execute the method being passed as a property (onRemove()) and instead I get (Firefox):

```
TypeError: _this2 is undefined
```

and in Chrome I get:

```
Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
```

I don't get why it can't find the function though, I did a previous tutorial which did exactly this and it's able to find the function ok. I've probably overlooked something really simple.

[EDIT: Extra Board Info]

```
//Board's render method
render() {
    return (
        <div className='board'>
            { this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote) }
        </div>
    );
}
```

In the console it outputs what I expect.

Comment: Could you post more code of `Board` class.

Comment: It seems that you need to bind `this` to the `remove()` method that is defined in `Board`, or make it an arrow function to have this defined on your behalf.

Comment: Hello, I'll update the main question with more info about board. @brandNew I already use an arrow function, it should bind automatically.

Answer (score 0):

after an afternoon of trying everything under the sun, I would like to show my solution in case anybody else had this problem.

My render method is mapping through an array of notes and creating  from each element. The problem was that I wasn't passing a 'notes' object to the function which created the note element. So I fixed it by changing my render method to this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className='board'>
            { this.state.notes.map((note) => this.eachNote(note)) }
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm not sure but I think this works because each Note instance has it's own this given to it. If someone has a better explanation please let me know.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly that the "child" component handel the click,
But the click does not propagate the the parent component  (Board).

In Board, you are changing this.state (correctly) but passed along to the "chil" component, "this" changes.

Try (Board):
This.remove = this.remove.bind (this);

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html